# Weka: file not recognized as csv data files

Tags: csv, machine-learning, weka

[image]

my line 1 is:

```
column0,column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column11,column12,column13,column14,column15,column16,column17,column18,column19,column20
```

line 2 is:

```
225,1,9d36efa8d56c724ceb5b8834873d5457,38.69.182.103,,,,,,3,62930,0,,,,,6f4b457b6044ccd205dcf5531582af54,Apache-HttpClient%2fUNAVAILABLE%20%28java%201.4%29,1646,,160807,1
```